# hyperlink "active" style not working?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make "Forgot password?" hyperlink active in my html. Current screen-shot of my web page is http://prntscr.com/2q6mf8 . And desired screen is http://prntscr.com/2q6mmr .  Here "Sign-in" is the class of my global "div". I have the below HTML :

```
<div class="visible-xs sign-in">    

    <div id="login-form">


        <div class="login-form-header">
            <div class="logo-SI">
                <img src="/web/resources/localadventures/img/la_logo.png" />
            </div>
            <h2 class="page-title-SI green-bg">Local Adventures</h2>
        </div>

        <a href="#" class="login-form-control" style="position: relative; top: 4px;">Create an Account</a>
        <a href="#" class="login-form-control" style="position: relative; top: 4px;">Sign In</a>

        <input type="email" required value="Email Address" style="position: relative; top: 10px;" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Email Address'" onFocus="if(this.value=='Email Address')this.value='' ">
        <input type="email" required value="Password" style="position: relative; top: 10px;" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Password'" onFocus="if(this.value=='Password')this.value='' ">

        <br>

        <div>
            <p align="right"><font color="green"><a href="" class="signin-form-control active" style="position: relative; left: 25px; top: 14px;">Forgot your password?</a></font></p>
        </div>

        <br>
        <span class='btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block'>Sign In</span>
        <span class='btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block'>Facebook Sign In</span>

    </div> 

</div>
```

My CSS is below:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* ---------- GENERAL ---------- */

a {
    color: #2a2a2a;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: right;
    margin:1px 25;
}

a:hover { color: #88c425; }

.sign-in .fieldset {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.sign-in .btn-success {
 border-radius:0px;
 background-color: #88c425
}

.sign-in .btn-success:hover {
background-color: #88c425
}

.sign-in .btn-primary {
 border-radius:0px;
}

.sign-in input {
    border: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.sign-in input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type="submit"] { cursor: pointer; }

.sign-in.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }
.sign-in.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table; 
}
.sign-in.clearfix:after { clear: both; }

/* ---------- LOGIN-FORM ---------- */

.sign-in #login-form {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 300px;
}

.sign-in #login-form h3 {
    background-color: #79a002;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.sign-in #login-form fieldset {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 0 0 -1px -1px;
    padding: 0px;

}

.sign-in #login-form fieldset:before {
    background-color: #fff;
    content: "";
    height: 8px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -4px 0 0 -4px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 8px;
}

.sign-in #login-form input {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.sign-in #login-form input[type="email"], #login-form input[type="password"] {
    border:none; /* clear previous borders */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #88c425; /* add bottom border */
    padding: 12px 10px;
    width: 300px;
}

.sign-in #login-form input[type="email"] {
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

.sign-in #login-form input[type="password"] {
    border-top: none;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
}

.sign-in #login-form input[type="submit"] {
    background: #1dabb8;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
}

.sign-in.login-form-header {
    overflow:hidden; /* clearfix */    
    background:#88C425;
}

.logo-SI {
    float:left;
    top:-5px;
}

.page-title-SI {
    margin:0;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height:75px; /* height of the logo image to center text verticaly */
    margin-left:76px;
    position: relative;
    top:-5px;
}

.sign-in.login-form-controls {
    overflow:hidden;
}

.sign-in.login-form-control {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:50%;

}
.sign-in.signin-form-control{
    display:block;
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    color: #88c425;

}

.sign-in.login-form-control > span {
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
}

.sign-in.active.login-form-control {
    color:#88C425;
}
```

As you can observe, i added "active" for "Forgot passowrd?" hyper link in HTML, this is not working!. I have also tried editing

```
.sign-in.signin-form-control{
    display:block;
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    color: #88c425;

}
```

in CSS by adding "a" in the style. Nothing seems to work. I want the link to appear in green as soon as the page loads. What change needs to be done to fix this?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This CSS selector:

```
.sign-in.active.login-form-control
```

does not match the classes of your HTML element:

```
<a class="signin-form-control active">Forgot your password?</a>
```

It seems that the selector should be:

```
.signin-form-control.active
```

[Working Example (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/KxJDG/)

Comment: showdev: That worked !. New to CSS, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Kriz, for future reference, you can use the Dev Tools (F12), and look at your elements' styles. It can let you know what is being applied, and the origins of each computed style.